# WCF / non WCF for duplex tc/ip which one is better suited?

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I'm currently in the process of creating a Service that is reachable (thus listens) via tcp and gets accessed by up to 1000 Clients. The Connection itself being Duplex (thus the Server sends back to the Client via the same Connection)

After going through all the wcf and non wcf tutorials and documentations I'm a bit confused and unsure there.

From what it Looks: WCF is easier to use than manually doing things. At least when it Comes to http Connections. For tcp Connections one almost always only finds manual (thus non wcf) tutorials and informations.

As None of the tutorials or documentations were conclusive there the question is:
Is there any info available if WCF is really suitable for Duplex tcp/ip Connections or if non WCF is better suited there?

Comment: WCF duplex is quit easy to implement, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services. Using SignalR might be an option as well, https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: @PeterBons yepp Duplex with wcf is quite easy. only Thing I noticed there was that it was ALWAYS http Duplex never tcp (or as good as never to be exact). Thus I'm wondering there what I'm overlooking there why tcp + wcf+ Duplex is as good as never in any example and documentation (in effect thus if I'm overlooking an intrinsic disadvantage there or not)

Comment: but that's just a matter of changing the endpoint. Whether you are using tcp or http does not change anything about how to setup the duplex part. But anyway, see http://realfiction.net/2008/01/30/The-no-frills-bare-bones-example-to-Duplex-WCF/ for a tcp based example.